# Unable to import android.server.* package

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I am trying to use android.server.ProcessStats class to get cpu usage statistics (pcpu, idle time, etc) of my app on android device, but I'm not able to import the package android.server
required to use this class. After searching on the net, I came to know that android.server package is not the part of standard SDK.

Can anyone please tell me how/where should I find this package. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There you go](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/com/android/server/ProcessStats.java). The rest of the package is also included.

Comment: Oh, and if you are new to StackOverflow, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Have a nice day !